# highcharts zoom series dissapeares

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/skvjo06h/5/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
                 chart: {
                    type: 'column',
                    zoomType: 'x',        
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'linear',
                    labels: {
                        rotation: -45,
                        align: 'right'
                    },                                      
                },  
                series: [{
                    name: "Histogram",
                    data: dataHistogram,                    
                }],
                title: { text: 'Histogram' },
                subtitle: { text: ' To '  },
                yAxis: [{//Primary axis
                    title: { text: 'Values' },

                },]
            })
});
```

With histogram data. I have set the zoom option for x axis. But when i zoom some parts  of the chart ( for example the left side from middle - the yaxis with the columns dissapreares.

Is fixed once the chart is reset.

What could be the problem ?- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your data should be sorted by x ascending, but is not. (Check console error).

Comment: That was the problem. !!
Thanks ! - Thought if it already displayed the series, it would be ok.